# Keeping track of the position of 'the cursor' in a doubly linked list (Java)

Tags: java, cursor, doubly-linked-list

I have implemented a DLL for adding and deleting characters. The purpose of the code is to give the output for registered keypresses. An example is that 'bai-d' will give 'bad' (the '-' represents the backspace).
So far these adding and deleting operations are going fine. But the registered keypresses also contain '<' and '>', which represent the shift of the cursor to the left and the right. An example is 'ball< < d > >--' which has to give 'bad'.
I find it hard to come up with a method to include the '<' and '>' in my code.

```
            MyLinkedList newList = new MyLinkedList();
            String password = input.nextLine();

            for (char ch : password.toCharArray()){
                if(Character.isLetter(ch) || Character.isDigit(ch)){
                    newList.addRear(ch);
                    }

                if(ch == '-'){
                    newList.removeRear();                       
                }
                /*if(ch == '<'){
                    //cursor shifting

                }
                if(ch == '>'){
                    //cursor shifting
                }*/
        }   

            newList.print();

}
```

Here I just call the methods for the characters. In the following section I will put a part of my implementation of the DLL. I have methods for the size, inserting at the front and back, deleting from the front and back.

```
public void removeFront(){ 
    if(head==null) return;

    head = head.next;
    head.previous = null;
    size--;
}

public void removeRear(){ 
    if(head==null) return;
    if(head.next == null){
        head = null;
        size--;
        return; 
    }
    Link current = head;
    while(current.next.next != null){
        current = current.next;
    }
    current.next = null;
    size--;
}
public void addFront(char data){ 
    if(head==null){
        head = new Link(null, data, null);
        }

    else{
        if(Character.isLetter(data) || Character.isDigit(data)){
            Link newLink = new Link(null, data, head); 
            head.previous = newLink; 
            head = newLink; 
        }
    }
    size++;
}

public void addRear(char data){ 
    if (head==null){
        head= new Link(null, data, null);   
    }
    else{
        Link current = head;
        while(current.next != null){
            current = current.next;
        }
        Link newLink = new Link(current, data, null);
        current.next = newLink;
    }
    size++;
}
```

I would appreciate your help and suggestions!

Comment: Grab a pen and paper and draw out your examples. See where the 'cursor' should be when performing the different operations and what should happen to the `next` and `previous` references in your `Link`s when deleting / adding at these positions. You'll need to introduce a class field which references the correct `Link` at all times and allow for operations such as move right, move left to navigate the linked list, as well as delete and add for the `Link` at the current cursor position. You can always take some inspiration from the `ListIterator` in Java's `LinkedList` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shift your Front and rear pointer based on < or >